# A System of Inequalites arising from the Divisors of a Number, Showing Its Non-Solvability

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, inequality, linear-programming

Let $n$ be a natural number. Denote by $d(n)$ the number of divisors of $n$, i.e. with the notation from [Wikipedia:Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) we have $d(n) = \sigma_0(n)$. Suppose we have the $d(n) - 2$ variables
$$
 x_d, \quad d | n, \quad d \notin \{ 1, n \}.
$$
and the system of linear inequalities 
$$
 \sum_{\substack{k | d \\ k \ne 1}} x_k \le d - 1
$$
for all $d$ with $d$ divides $n$ and $d \notin \{1,n\}$. Further
$$
 x_d \ge 0
$$
for all variables $x_d$ and their sum should equal $n$. Then I want to show that this system of inequalites and one equality has no solution.

For an **example** let $n = 12$. Then the variables are
$$
 x_2, x_3, x_4, x_6
$$
and the inequalities and one equality:
\begin{align*}
 x_2 & \le 1 \\
 x_2 + x_4 & \le 3 \\
 x_3 & \le 2 \\
 x_2 + x_3 + x_6 & \le 5 \\
 x_2, x_3, x_4, x_6 & \ge 0 \\
 x_2 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_6 & = 12.
\end{align*}
And this system has no solution, as I found by using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%3C%3D1%2C%20a%2Bc%3C%3D3%2C%20a%2Bb%2Bd%3C%3D5%2C%20a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd%3D12%2C%20a%3E%3D0%2C%20b%3E%3D0%2C%20c%3E%3D0%2C%20d%3E%3D0).

Comment: did you mean $\sum_{\substack{k | d \\ k \ne 1}} x_k \le d - 1$?

Comment: yes, of course, I edited my post!

Comment: $x_2+x_3+x_6\le5$ you mean.

Comment: yes, forgot that too, thank you!